# is it possible to dynamic row in jinja template

Tags: ansible

I want to add row in my jinja template base on number rows in my file.
for example. my file having 3 row then jinja template should be like below.
suppose my row getting increase in file then row should automatically added into jinja template at time of reddening.
I  am taking count from file

```
{% for item in join_out.stdout_lines %}
<tr>
{%  set row = item.split(" ") %}
<td align="center">{{ row[0] | replace('"','') }}</td>
<td align="center">{{ row[1] | replace('"','') }}</td>
<td align="center">{{ row[2] | replace('"','') }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: you should be able to iterate over `row` using `for` loop after you split it. maybe call it `rows` instead, since it's multiple rows

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new for loop on the ***set row = item.split(" ")*** to loop over the items on that list, and you don't ever have to use the list index.

```
{% for item in join_out.stdout_lines %}
<tr>
{%  set rows = item.split(" ") %}
{% for row in rows %}
  <td align="center">{{ row | replace('"','') }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Although this might answer OPs question, you should add some explanation of what your code is doing exactly and why it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the quotation marks and split the lines first. Then simply create the table. For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    join_out:
      stdout_lines:
        - '"A1" "B1"'
        - '"A2" "B2"'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_data: "{{ my_data|default([]) + [item.split(' ')] }}"
      loop: "{{ join_out.stdout_lines|
                map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                list }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '"'
        my_replace: ''
    - copy:
        content: |
          <table>
          {% for line in my_data %}
          <tr>
          {%  for row in line %}
          <td align="center">{{ row }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </table>
        dest: table.html
```

gives

```html
shell> cat table.html
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">A1</td>
<td align="center">B1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">A2</td>
<td align="center">B2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```